# Setting an image in ListView item using SimpleCursorAdapter and ViewBinder

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-viewbinder

Is there a way I could set an image to an `ImageView` inside a `ListView`? In this, I am using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to display all the fields and using a `ViewBinder` to set the image bitmap to the `ImageView`. The image is downloaded using an `AsyncTask`. The code that I have written is provided below:

```
    private void updateTimelineUI() {
        Cursor data = dbHelper.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
        if (data.moveToFirst()) {
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.tweet_row, data, new String[] {Constants.CREATED_TIME, Constants.USERNAME, Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE, Constants.TWEET}, new int[] {R.id.time, R.id.username, R.id.userImageView, R.id.tweetMessage});
            SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder viewBinder = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                    if(view != null && view.getId() != R.id.userImageView) {
                        return false;
                    }
                String imageUrlString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                String username = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.USERNAME));
                String path = getDir("images", MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + username + ".png";
                ImageDownloader downloader = new ImageDownloader();
                downloader.setImageUrlString(imageUrlString);
                downloader.setImageView(view);
                downloader.setFilePath(path);
                downloader.execute(imageUrlString);
                return true;
                }
            };
            int index = data.getColumnIndex(Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE);
            //Log.d(Constants.TAG, "" + index);
            adapter.setViewBinder(viewBinder);
            viewBinder.setViewValue(userImageView, data, index);
            timelineList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to set the image to the correct row with this method?

*With the code that I currently have, the images are downloaded successfully. However, the images are being set randomly.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your own adapter which shall inherit from SimpleCursorAdapter and therefore you can make your own ListView item with your custom design and set a custom layout for it in which you can add whatever Ui element that you want including ImageView

Comment: So there is no other way other than writing my own adapter? I am able to set the image to the imageView but the image keeps randomly changing so I was wondering if anything could be done with the current code.

Comment: The point is that if you dont make your own adapter while you are scrolling the list the listItem wouldnt know what and which picture   to render and that's why it'll render different images thus leading to changing images for every scrolling.That is why you need to implement your own adapter and keep track of your items in every ListItem.

Answer (score 2):

I created a custom class that inherits from `SimpleCursorAdapter`, like Serdar Dogruyol mentions.  Inside this custom class I `@Override bindView`.  Inside `bindView` I call the `super`, then get a handle to my `ImageView` using `view.findViewById`, with `view` being one of the parameters passed into `bindView`.